# phonegap/cordova android crash when getting facebook-synced image from photo library

Tags: android, cordova, android-camera

I'm building a Phonegap/Cordova (2.2.0) app for Android that has a feature where the user is prompted to take a picture or select from the photo library.

When taking a new photo with the camera everything works as it should and the same goes for when selecting any picture from the library except from those that have been synced with my Facebook account (as far as I've been able to test).

The error happens when the app is resumed and is passed the image, there's a null exception when loading the bitmap inside of cordova. I've tried to remove resizing, orientation change and reduced the quality and tried resizing with very small maximums.

The device I'm testing on is a Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.2

Thanks

Comment: show the stack trace from "adb logcat"

Comment: Hi Purkela, did you solve this problem? I am having the same issue!